# Getting the name of the current user (not the username)

Tags: c#, winforms

I've read a few posts about getting the name of the current user which use either of the following methods:

```
Environment.UserName;
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
```

This gets the username of teh current logged in user but what I'm wondering about is how to get the name of the user that is logged in?
(thus not the login but the name that is also saved and displayed when you lock the computer)

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.Current;
String name = userPrincipal.DisplayName;
```

this code works for me